# How to get SharePoint list field value of type person or group using ecmascript or SPServices?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, ecmascript-6, spservices

Following is my code...

```
function retrieveListItems() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('list name');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + < Value Type = \'Integer\'>413</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += 'Title: ' + oListItem.get_item('Writer').get_lookupValue();
    }
    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

I even tried with `oListItem.get_item('Writer').get_title()` but it is not working..
Sometime it returns undefined...
Please help..

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for list item 'Created By' value then use 'Author' instead of 'Writer' or if you want 'Modified By' value then use 'Editor' instead of 'Writer'.

Comment: I reworded your request to something more accurate: "Danny Please remember to upvote if you find this answer useful and mark as Answer if it solves your problem."